# Why can't I reset the state of my variable? (Or go back to the initial state)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, reset

I have some state in my application, and I'm trying to reset its value when I click a button.

When the page is rendered for the first time, `handleAllProjects` is executed:

```
const [tagPage, setTagPage] = useState({});

const handleAllProjects = () => {
setTagPage({}) // didn't work

    const allProjects = `https://api.fluxoresultados.com.br/portfolio/pag?limit=${cardLimit}`;
    axios.get(allProjects)
    .then(res => {
      let cards = res.data
      setCards(cards)
      setTagPage({1: "", 2: cards[cards.length - 1]["id"]})
      setCurrentPage(1)
      console.log(currentPage) //line 61
      console.log(tagPage) //line 62
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
```

I also have the following button click event handler:

```
const handleSelectButton = (id, tag) => {
  if (id === pressedIndex) {
  setPressedIndex('')
  setTimeout(handleAllProjects, 500);

} else {
  setPressedIndex(id)
  setTimeout(() => handleTag(tag), 500);
}
```

}
}

The intent of this function is that it will filter projects when clicked for the first time, but when clicked again, it will render everything using the `handleAllProjects` function.
My page renders 6 projects on cards. setTagPage takes the "id" of the last project, because DynamoDB requires this for pagination. On this page there are filters for projects. When I apply the filter, setTagPage takes another "id". When I remove the filter (I go back to the state where the page renders for the first time). SetTagPage does not reset the value, and brings the "id" of the page as if there were still the filter.

However, the `TagPage` variable contains a tag, instead of being reset to its initial state. [Here's an example of what I'm talking about - I need the `console.log` statement on line 62 to be the same as before.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7AVt.png) How can I reset this value back to its initial state?

Comment: Your `setTimeout`s will be executing immediately in their current implementation, you are executing the function and passing it's results into the timeout, rather than passing the function itself. (This can be valid, but it doesn't look intentional in this case)

Comment: If you are using `useState` for all set functions, the state variables are not being updated immediately. So your `console.log` statements will most likely print outdated values.

Comment: You need `setTimeout(handleAllProjects, 500);` and `setTimeout(() => handleTag(tag), 500);`, or the function is called right away, not after the timeout.

Comment: @DBS Do you recommend that I no longer use setTimeOut?

Comment: @ChrisG i did it, but didn't work here... (edited the code of question too)

Comment: @Christiaan what do you recommend i do in this case?

Comment: I'm not seeing `setTagPage({})` anywhere; isn't that what would reset it? Also keep in mind that setting state is *async*; logging it right after setting it will log the previous state.

Comment: @ChrisG i updated the code, i put the setTagPage({}) at the begining of the function....
regardless of what appears in Console.Log, the variable is not resetting, because my application is not working properly

Comment: So what is your issue here? Is it that the else statement is not being executed? 
On line 59 you set the tags to some specific values after the fetch, so that's why don't get the empty object when the ```handleAllProjects``` is called. 
Can you create a smallest reproducible example of your code?

Comment: @szczocik I updated the question and left your question explained

Comment: Don't console log your state values after setting them. Instead, console log them in the render function or in a separate `useEffect` hook with these variables as dependencies. The reason why you don't see the correct values is demonstrated in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-usestate-update-order-50orm?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: I created an effect for the consolelog's and managed to solve my problem, thanks guys!